# I am using react hooks for a little music project I'm working on. How can I make state change in only the div affected?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

I am mapping out 4 divs. They print out like I want, each div showing their corresponding number in an h2 and the default chord 'C'.

I have a dropdown with options A-G. I want the h1 to change the chord to the new chord in only the div it was selected in.

The chord does change, but in all of the divs. How do I make it so that state changes for that particular div only? Is this possible? I know I could write a separate state for each div, it's only four but I want it cleaner than that if possible. Any ideas? I'm sure most of you will be able to spot the problem right away. Thanks in advance for help.

```js
    function Grid() {
      const [chord, setChord] = useState("C");

     const number = [1, 2, 3, 4]

      return (
        number.map(number =>
      <div style={left}>

        <div style={styles} className="col-">
          <h1 style={keyStyle}>{chord}</h1>
          <h2 key={number}>{number.toString()}.</h2>

          <label for="key">KEY </label>

          <select
            style={dropdownStyles}

            onChange={e => setChord(e.target.value)}

          >
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="dm">dm</option>
            <option value="em">em</option>
            <option value="F">F</option>
            <option value="G">G</option>
            <option value="am">am</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>


    )

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your state with an Array, instead of a single String value, as follows:

```
function Grid() {
      // Initialize an Array state with 4 entries for each div: 
      const [chord, setChord] = React.useState(["C","C","C","C"]);
     // Rename list to 'numbers'. Naming matters.
     const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
      return (
        numbers.map((number,idx) =>
      <div style={left}>
        <div style={styles} className="col-">
          {/* Use the current div's number, minus 1 to display the appropriate state value */}
          <h1 style={keyStyle}>{ chord[idx] }</h1>
          <h2 key={number}>{number.toString()}.</h2>
          <label for="key">KEY </label>
          {/* Update the state using the current div's number: */}
          <select
            style={dropdownStyles}
            onChange={e => {
                            // Get a copy of the current state:
                            const _chord = chord.slice();
                            // Change the entry for the specified div:
                            _chord[idx] = e.target.value;
                            // Update the state:
                            setChord(  _chord );
                        }}
          >
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="dm">dm</option>
            <option value="em">em</option>
            <option value="F">F</option>
            <option value="G">G</option>
            <option value="am">am</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  );
}
```

You can also use the `spread` operator to get a copy of the chords array inside the event handlers:

```js
const _chord = [ ...chord ];
```

---

**Note:** You should also consider renaming the array `number` to `numbers` (list of elements require plural) or you will be looking for troubles, since you are also using the `number` inside the map callback. Make sure the two names correspond to different values.

Comment: Bearing in mind the `numbers` array should also read `[0, 1, 2, 3]` or `numbers.map` will have to reference the index rather than the number itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have so much to learn but this is great. I appreciate it

Comment: Just updated the code, in order for it to work with any kind of values in the `numbers` array. The code now uses the array index number to sync it with the state array instead of the array value. Thanks to @Lazarus for pointing this out. ;)